# SQL INSERT...SELECT with auto-increment DATETIME

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the following structure :

```
userid, entrydatetime, record.
```

`tableA` - has primary key `(userid, entrydatetime)`

`tableB` - has no constraints set.

I am trying to do an

`INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * FROM tableB` ,

but I am getting an error because `tableB` has all the same `userid` and `entrydatetime`.

e.g. userid = '12345' and entrydatetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

the main data that I need from `tableB` are `userid` and record. `entryDateTime` is less critical to me for this scenario.

How can I merge my two tables yet keeping my `tableA` primary key constraint? Is there a way I can randomize or autoincrement the `entrydatetime` field on insert?

Comment: how can you have two columns `userid, entrydatetime` as **PRIMARY**?

Comment: Its called a Composite primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following query

```
SET @value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
INSERT INTO tableA 
(user_id, entrydatetime, record) 
(SELECT user_id, @value := @value + INTERVAL 1 SECOND, record from tableB);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: hmmm that didnt work for me because the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will still be the same for all the records i am inserting.

Comment: What is your datatype for entrydatetime? is it DATETIME or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: wow that worked perfect thank you so so much. i also learnt from your solution that i can use variables like that in sql. thanks again!